# Как удалять куки при переходе на следующую страницу?

Tags: php, cookie, сессия

Здравствуйте, как как удалять куки при переходе на следующую страницу ?
То есть мы зашли на страницу site.ru/res?id=1 и сохранили id страницы (и сделали переадресацию на страницу, которая сохранилась в куки(в данном случае страница site.ru/res?id=1), то есть когда заходишь на страницу site.ru/res перенаправляет на site.ru/res?id=1)
Если к примеру мы хотим перейти на страницу site.ru/res?id=2 то перенаправляет на страницу site.ru/res?id=1 так как она записалась в куки.
А можно сделать, что к примеру я перешел на другую страницу сайта и куки обновлялись следующей страницей: вот код

```
$we = $_GET['page']; // равно 1

setcookie("s34", $we);

if ($_COOKIE["s34"]) {
$cookiepage = $_COOKIE["s34"];
header("Location: site.ru/res?id=$cookiepage");
}
<a href="site.ru/res?id=2"> Статья</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
$we = $_GET['page']; // равно 1

unset($_COOKIE['s34']);
setcookie("s34", $we);

if ($_COOKIE["s34"]) {
$cookiepage = $_COOKIE["s34"];
header("Location: site.ru/res?id=$cookiepage");
}
<a href="site.ru/res?id=2"> Статья</>
```

Поскольку похоже на то, что вы добавляете много кук с одним именем. И выбирается просто первый.